# Edit a vbscript file to change file location using PHP

Tags: php, csv, vbscript

I have a working vbscript file that will convert excel files to csv. Here's the question that its coming to my mind since this vbscript is also part of my php program that I'm working on.... The vbscript file contains a location which will get the files and convert them.   I want to change the location of the vbscript code using a php. Any hints on how to do this? I was searching google and only found vbscript editors online but not usning Php.

Here's the vbscript code

```
Option Explicit

Dim oFSO, myFolder
Dim xlCSV

myFolder="C:\Users\HP\Desktop\ExcelFiles"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by reading the vbs file and replacing the `myFolder` line:

```
<?php

// Read file into array
$data = file('test.vbs');

// This is the location we want
$newLocation = 'C:\\AnotherLocation';

// Read each line and try to find the myFolder string
$data = array_map(function($line) use ($newLocation) {
    // If we have myFolder make sure it's followed by a path of some kind, capture
    // this path into $matches
    preg_match('/myFolder="([A-Za-z:\\\\]+)/', $line, $matches);

    // Replace old path with new path
    if (count($matches)) {
        $line = str_replace($matches[1], $newLocation, $line);
    }

    return $line;
}, $data);

// Replace contents of file with new location
file_put_contents('test.vbs', implode('', $data));
```

Comment: THIS WORKED GREAT!! :D just what I've been looking for my program :)